# Using scpi commands on python with mac Ventura - is this possible?

Tags: python, pyvisa

I am trying to use easy_scpi.

However, this says that it requires a backend. I am not able to find a backend compatible with Ventura 13.3.1.

Is it not possible to use this library on Ventura 13.3.1 for this reason? Is there a workaround or an alternative backend to NI-VISA?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the pyvisa-py backend. It is a pure python implementation of the VISA standard.
For that, you have to install the `pyvisa-py` python package (see it's [documentation](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/projects/pyvisa-py/en/latest/index.html)). If it is installed, it should get recognized automatically. If that doesn't work, you can pass `"@py"` as the backend to the instrument constructor, eg.

```py
instr = scpi.Instrument("TCPIP::192.168.0.123::INSTR", backend="@py")`
```

Note: to use other interface classes apart from TCPIP (eg. GPIB), you might need to install additional packages or use another backend alltogether. NI-VISA seems to be available for macOS so I would suggest to try that one.